# Identity linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

For a linear transformation $A$ it is known that $A^3=A$. $A$ is the linear transformation over finite dimensional vector space $V$. Now I am supposed to prove that

$$\ker (A-I) + \operatorname{im} (A-I) = V$$

where $\ker$ means a set of vectors which are transformed to zero vector

$\operatorname{im}$ is image of $A-I.$

And $+$ is the direct sum

I identity matrix

What I want to know is, is $A=I $? If it is, is there a way to prove it? And if it's not, what else could it be?

Comment: It is not necessarily true that $A = I$. It is also possible that $A = -I$ or that $A=0$.  There are many things that $A$ could be.

Comment: So is there any way to find out what $A $ might be? Or to prove this equation without knowing what $A $ actually is?

Comment: This equation is one essential step in order to describe all solutions.

Comment: @Berci is it that A^3 - A = 0, A(A^2 - I)=0. So now I multiply it from the left with A^-1 and get A^2=I. Now what? I get that A can be either I or -I, so how can I use this to continue.

Comment: A matrix is not a number. Noone said $A$ has an inverse. $A^2=I$ holds for infinitely many matrices (consider reflections through lines in the plane).

Comment: @Berci Okay, so is it actuality necessary to know what A is in order to prove what I need to prove? Could you help my with the proof itself?

Comment: No, not necessary for sure. We have to do some algebra here, let me think.. Btw, from dimension theorem, it's enough to proof that ${\rm im}(A-I)\cap\ker(A-I)=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, $A=I$ is certainly one solution for $A^3=A$, but not the only solution, e.g. $0$ or any reflection as a linear transformation is a solution, in particular $A=-I$.

Suppose $v\in{\rm im}(A-I)\cap\ker(A-I)$, i.e. $v=(A-I)u$ for some $u$, and $Av=v$. 
We want to prove $v=0$. For that,
$$0=(A^3-A)u=A(A+I)(A-I)u=A(A+I)v=A^2v+Av\\
A^2v=-Av$$
But we also have $Av=v$ and thus $A^2v=A(Av)=Av=v$, the above line thus gives $v=-v$.

Now, with the dimension theorem for $A-I$ (having $\dim({\rm im}(A-I))+\dim(\ker(A-I))=\dim V$), the proof completes.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. Thank you!

Comment: Great! : ) $\,\!\,$

Comment: just one more quick question. If you could explain a bit more the last part with the dimensions, I am not sure I fully understand how to use it. thanks